# NoneType Buffer interface error in windows 8

Tags: file, python-3.x, tkinter, buffer

I am making a text editor, so you can imagine that there is a lot of manipulating text files. When I double click on the .py file to run it in python.exe in windows, it throws an error of 'NoneType does not support the Buffer interface' As I have only ever heard "buffer" as a programming term in the context of text files, I believe the problem is somewhere in there.

Here is the code:

```python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import os

os.chdir(os.getenv('HOME'))

current=None
backup=''

def newfile():

    def create_file(entry):
        global current
        global root
        nonlocal create_in
        nonlocal name_it
        current = open(entry.get(),'w')
        root.title(create_in+'/'+current.name+' - Aspus')
        name_it.destroy()

    create_in=askdirectory()
    if create_in!='':
        global root
        os.chdir(create_in)
        name_it=Tk()
        name_it.title("Name the File?")
        prompt=Label(name_it, text="Enter name for new file:")
        prompt.grid(row=0)
        entry=Entry(name_it)
        entry.grid(row=1)
        entry.insert(0, "Untitled.txt")
        create=Button(name_it, text="Create", command = lambda: create_file(entry))
        create.grid(row=1, column=3)
        name_it.mainloop()

def openfile(master):
    global current
    global backup
    opening=askopenfilename()
    file=open(opening, 'r')
    insert=file.read()
    backup=file.read()
    file.close()
    file=open(opening, 'w')
    current=file
    master.title(current.name+' - Aspus')
    return insert

def savefile(entry):
    global current
    if current!=None:
        current.write(entry.get('1.0', END))

    elif current==None:
        newfile()
        current.write(entry.get('1.0', END))

def ask_save():
    global root
    global current
    global main
    if current!=None:
        save_exit=askyesnocancel("Save Before Exit?", "Do you want to save before exiting?")
        if save_exit==True:
            a=current.name
            current.close()
            current=open(a, 'w')
            savefile(main)
            current.close()
            root.destroy()
            exit()
        elif save_exit==False:
            a=current.name
            current.close()
            current=open(a, 'w')
            current.write(backup)
            current.close()
            root.destroy()
            exit()
    elif current==None:
        if main.get('0.1', END).strip()!='':
            save_exit=askyesnocancel("Save Before Exit?", "Do you want to save before exiting?")
            if save_exit==True:
                newfile()
                savefile()
                current.close()
                root.destroy()
            elif save_exit==False:
                root.destroy()
        else:
            root.destroy()

def setpgwidth():

    def adjust(entry):
        global main
        new_width=entry.get()
        try:
            main.config(width=int(entry.get()))
        except:
            showerror("Invalid width", "You entered an invalid width. Expected an integer.")
            entry.delete(0, END)
        else:
            main.pack(expand=Y, fill=Y, side=LEFT)
            entry.master.destroy()

    width=Tk()
    width.title("Set Page Width")
    prompt=Label(width, text="Enter new page width:")
    prompt.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
    new=Entry(width)
    new.grid(row=1, column=0)
    submit=Button(width, text="Submit", command=lambda: adjust(new))
    submit.grid(row=1, column=1)
    width.mainloop()

root=Tk()
root.title("Aspus Text Editor")

#create main text widget
main=Text(root, wrap=WORD)
main.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

#create scrollbar
scroll=Scrollbar(root)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

#configure scrollbar
scroll.config(command=main.yview)
main.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

#Creating menus
menu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
menu.add_command(label="New File", command=newfile)
menu.add_command(label="Open File", command=lambda: main.insert(END, openfile(root)))
menu.add_command(label="Save File", command=lambda: savefile(main))
formatmenu=Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Format", menu=formatmenu)
formatmenu.add_command(label="Set Page Width", command=setpgwidth)
menu.add_command(label="Quit", command=ask_save)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", ask_save)

root.mainloop()
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to avoid  it?

Comment: please show the full stacktrace.

Comment: Error messages typically include the line number, and the function that was called.

Comment: Not this one. Just what I said, nothing else

Comment: Run the script from a command prompt and you should get a complete stack trace.

Comment: @BryanOakley This was on a school computer, where the command prompt is disabled

Comment: @BryanOakley I noticed that some other programs were having this problem, all of them using tkinter. I think that tkinter was trying to get some sort of environment variable, but since it was a school computer with all sorts of strange quirks to the filesystem and OS due to the restrictions set in place by the school, that was a NoneType. Then, tkinter tries to do something to it that involves the buffer interface, and I get this error.

Comment: What you wrote makes no sense. It's not a tkinter problem. The problem is almost certainly with one of your write statements.

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem is these two statements:

```
insert=file.read()
backup=file.read()
```

Because `read()` reads the whole file, `backup` isn't going to be what you think it is.

The first thing to do is step through the code with pdb, or add some print statements to validate that your data is what you think it is. You're relying heavily on global variables which can easily be changed in an order different than what you expect.

Comment: I figured it out, and what I said made **total** sense. There was a stack trace, but the window was disappearing before I could read it, so I took a screenshot of the screen with the error on it. t it was returning a NoneType because the computer was a school computer and there are all sorts of restrictions and quirks with the filesystem. I was trying use `chdir` on it, and that was what was throwing the error.